# Configure passwordless Azure SQL in Wildfly

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, wildfly, password-less

I'm trying to configure an application deployed to Wildfly 23 to connect to Azure SQL using managed identity and struggle to visualise how it is supposed to work in principle.
There are tons of articles and how-to in the internet on how to use passwordless connection to connect to Azure hosted databases. Most of them requires to include azure-identity.jar to the class path and use *authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI* option in jdbc connection string.
However, my application uses connection pool configured in wildly so adding azure-identity.jar to my application will not help. From my understanding I need to make azure-identity.jar available to wildfly, and I'm not sure how to do that. One idea is to register it as a module, I haven't tried that yet as I need to manage somehow dependencies of the jar.

So far, I changed my standalone file to include a datasource

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/passwordless" pool-name="pwls-ds" enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=aaa;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mssql-jdbc-12.4.1.jre11.jar</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                        <initial-pool-size>5</initial-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                </datasource>
```

When trying to test the connection I'm getting the following exception

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to load MSAL4J Java library for performing ActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity authentication

Any hint/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add [MSAL4J](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=azuresqldb-current#client-setup-requirements) including all dependencies on classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mssql-jdbc.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="msal4j.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="oauth2-oidc-sdk.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="json-smart.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="nimbus-jose-jwt.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="content-type.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="accessors-smart.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    <!-- msal4j -->
    <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind"/>
    <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations"/>
    <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Dependency binaries collect using

```
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/msal4j/1.13.10/msal4j-1.13.10.jar --output msal4j.jar &&
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/10.7.1/oauth2-oidc-sdk-10.7.1.jar --output oauth2-oidc-sdk.jar &&
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/minidev/json-smart/2.4.10/json-smart-2.4.10.jar --output json-smart.jar &&
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/9.30.2/nimbus-jose-jwt-9.30.2.jar --output nimbus-jose-jwt.jar &&
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/nimbusds/content-type/2.2/content-type-2.2.jar --output content-type.jar &&
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/minidev/accessors-smart/2.4.9/accessors-smart-2.4.9.jar --output accessors-smart.jar
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how to do that with Wildfly? I tried to wrap MSAL4j into a module but had no luck.

Comment: I would like to avoid fat jar so modify existing module: https://gist.github.com/amarkevich/8d1f10c67af1a79f2841482dbd7bfd46

Comment: thanks, for some reason we never did a module for JDBC driver before :(. You said 'existing' module, but I guess no such module exists by default, so I read it as 'create'. Please edit your answer and embed the gist for the module into the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Well, existing in legacy Keycloak container in my case

Answer (score 0):

To make it work I created a custom fat jar that combines both azure-identity and mssql-jdbc driver.Then I deploy it in the same way as a normal driver. For references the pom file to achieve that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.XXX.driver.sql</groupId>
<artifactId>XXX-sql-driver</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.jre11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>

            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I doubt it is the best solution it looks more like a workaround, so still on the hunt.